# Is there a way to show/hide some option and show/hide others in a select when an option is selected in a different select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-select

I am trying to create a select, which's options show/hide based on a selection in a previous select. I know there is a handful of different solutions out there to this problem, but I was unable to find a solution that would fit my problem, as they either were for example too complicated or did something slightly different such us showing and hiding whole selects rather than just options.

I was able to find one solution that was almost perfect.

http://jsfiddle.net/GhmzP/1/

The problem with this one was, that the first selection was made as a radio type input and I need it to be a select.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<select name="action">
    <option selected>check</option>
    <option>activate</option>
</select>

<select name="unit">
    <option class="sensor" value="s1">Sensor 1</option>
    <option class="sensor" value="s2">Sensor 2</option>
    <option class="sensor" value="s3">Sensor 3</option>
    <option class="sensor" value="s4">Sensor 4</option>

    <option class="relay" value="r1">Relay 1</option>
    <option class="relay" value="r2">Relay 2</option>
    <option class="relay" value="r3">Relay 3</option>
    <option class="relay" value="r4">Relay 4</option>
</select>
```

So to sum up, when check is selected in the first option, I want all of class sensor to be shown, and when activate is selected, I want all of class relay to be shown.

I tried modifying the js script from the aforementioned fiddle, but I didn't succeed. I would be very thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to achieve it.

```js
var $unit = $('[name="unit"]');

$('[name="action"]').change(function() {
  var cls = this.value === 'activate' ? '.relay' : '.sensor';
  $unit.find('option' + cls).show();
  $unit.val($unit.find('option' + cls + ':first').val());
  $unit.find('option:not(' + cls + ')').hide();
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="action">
  <option selected>check</option>
  <option>activate</option>
</select>

<select name="unit">
  <option class="sensor" value="s1">Sensor 1</option>
  <option class="sensor" value="s2">Sensor 2</option>
  <option class="sensor" value="s3">Sensor 3</option>
  <option class="sensor" value="s4">Sensor 4</option>

  <option class="relay" value="r1">Relay 1</option>
  <option class="relay" value="r2">Relay 2</option>
  <option class="relay" value="r3">Relay 3</option>
  <option class="relay" value="r4">Relay 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, 
this has worked and I thank you greatly for your time. It works perfectly on google chrome, but on safari, it still shows the sensor options. Would there be a way to make it work even in safari? Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielJanda : may be due to the backtick... updated to work with older browser